# Python list with space in the middle of list items

Tags: python, list, syntax-error, list-comprehension

I have a `list` which looks as follows:

```
lis = [1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9]
```

When running this I get a `SyntaxError`.

I want this list to contain three elements,

1. 1 2 3
2. 4 5 6
3. 7 8 9

The spaces are important and I am trying to avoid using `''` and `""`. Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: *"I am trying to avoid using '' and """* Could you explain your original requirement? This seems like XY.

Comment: The only way you can keep spaces, is if you are using strings. So you would need `''` or `""`. Depending on what you are using this for, you may be able to use lists instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need strings if you want to keep spaces:

```
data = ["1 2 3", "4 5 6", "7 8 9"]
```

Otherwise a list of lists/tuples can be used:

```
data = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
data = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
```

You may also want to try something like this:

```
data = [(1," ",2," ",3), (4," ",5," ",6), (7," ",8," ",9)]
```

The perfect solution really depends on your application

Answer (score 2):

`1 2 3` is not a valid form of data type in Python.

You can create a list of lists (2D list) by doing:

`[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

Alternatively, if you want them to be strings of text:

`["1 2 3", "4 5 6", "7 8 9"]`

Or, if you want them to be integers (numbers) only:

`[123, 456, 789]`

is an option.

Answer (score 1):

If you have spaces between the integers, there is currently no type of object in python that suppports that unless you parse them into strings. You could have 2D lists and put the 4 5 6 into [4,5,6] for example and extract from there

Answer (score 1):

You should know that `1 2 3` is not a string and integers.

In python list, Each elements of list should be a normal object.So you will get the exception.